# how to create tempalte or page for taxonomy archive

Tags: templates

i have cpt name X with 2 taxonomy "T1" and "T2"
i made these pages and every things work fine.

archive-x.php
single-x.php
taxonomy-T1.php
taxonomy-t2.php

now the problem is :
when i try to reach to some taxonomy i made under T1 like mydomain.com/t1/some its show taxonomy-T1.php and its ok
but when i use this link : mydomain.com/t1/ its show blank and showing 404

my goal is to make a template for that and using query on that page

Comment: yes thats the excat problem i have and im aware of that

Comment: also i dont want to use static page, i want to put it on my plugin, i need a function that say use this template if some one reached the parents links, something like showing all categories , ill do the query , i just need to say to wordpress that tempalte exist